# How can I extract data from a shared memory file, originally a C struct, into Go?

Tags: c, go, shared-memory, cgo

For a student project I'm trying to build an interface between Project Cars 2 which has a shared memory address where you can collect car telemetry data, and an embedded system communicating over UART.

I'd like to build it in Go and in the long run make a package for Go that can communicate and collect telemetry data and use it in the future. The shared memory struct and data is [written in C and found here](https://github.com/bglebrun/PCarsUART/blob/master/pcars/SharedMemory.h) [(source of this file)](https://www.projectcarsgame.com/project-cars-2-api/). When you access the memory mapped file "%pcars2%", this address contains the data in the organization of the linked struct.

My question is how's the best way to extract data from this struct? I understand I can use cgo and interpret the struct's data, but is there a way I could do a memory copy like in C directly in Go using a struct built from similar types from this address? I understand I can use the UDP API for telemetry data but am curious if Go has this sort of functionality.

Comment: You have access to the data, and to the types, so there's no reason you can't read it. What do you mean by a "memory copy like in C"? Assigning a value copies it.

Comment: Never have essential information on an external source. When the source disappears your question becomes useless for others. An important purpose of Stackoverflow is to archieve questions for other users.

Comment: Then maybe more specifically if a float and unsigned_int in C is the same as a float64 and uint64 in Golang, and if organizing the struct similarly in golang will yield the same data as doing a memcpy() in C of the struct.

Comment: Yes you should be able to, Go's [memory layout](https://go101.org/article/memory-layout.html) (on x86) is quite compatible with C. Just need to map C types to Go types carefully (e.g. int -> int32).

Comment: @BenLeBrun: `float` in C is single precision, and `unsigned_int` in C in 16 bits. There is always an equivalent, but you need to pick the correct size.